# Mono.Cecil Read Assembly on Linux

Tags: .net, mono.cecil

I need to reference a dotnet runtime assembly with Mono.Cecil on a Linux Machine. This is a 2 part question.

1. Where are the dotnet runtime assemblies stored on Linux (assuming it's an `.so` file)
2. Does the `Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition::ReadAssembly()` method accept `.so` files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where are the dotnet runtime assemblies stored on Linux (assuming it's an .so file)

You're assuming wrong, assemblies are stored as `.dll` files.

> Does the Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition::ReadAssembly() method accept .so files?

No, it works with .Net assembly files (`.dll`)

Comment: Yep, Thanks! Turns out you can easily print the assembly locations with MSBuild...
They're located in: `/usr/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/6.0.2/ref/net6.0/`. You're right, they're dlls.